# Windows 10 Often Freezes When Saving or Opening Files

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I've had this rather annoying issue since I first upgraded to Windows 10 (not via upgrade, but fresh install).

Whenever W10 opens the Open or Save dialog (i.e. you press Ctrl + S or Ctrl + O in most programs), about 8/10 times the dialog box will freeze for about 5-10 seconds before allowing you to do anything.

Has anybody else had this issue, and does anybody else know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out that the culprit was hard drive spin-down.

For those interested, you can increase hard drive idle detection time to a very high value or to "0" (never) in your Power Settings.

This keeps the hard drive running and you will no longer experience issues with wait times on dialogue Open or Save boxes, although it does keep your hard drive always running.

Answer (score 18):

Ok so I found a solution from here:

[Fix – Windows 10 Freeze Renaming – Saving Files and Folders](https://www.xgiovio.com/blog-photos-videos-other/blog/fix-windows-10-freeze-renaming-saving-files-and-folders/)

> If you use lots of shared folders (NAS and network in general), Windows 10 quick access algorithm could create troubles.
>
> Simply disable it to achieve again maximum response time from your system.
>
> To change how Quick Access works, display the File Explorer ribbon in any folder, navigate to View, and then select Options and then Change folder and search options. The Folder Options window opens.
>
> uncheck “Show frequently use folders in Quick access.”
>
> uncheck “Show recently used folders in Quick access.”
>
> press “Clear”

I made a GIF to show:

[image: gif]

Make sure both boxes in Privacy are unticked.

Comment: Can you include the relevant information from the link here?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Looks better yes

Comment: I don't have a NAS but for whatever reason, this really made a huge difference in my slowdown issue. THANK YOU.

Comment: I'd been suffering with this for weeks and tried so many things, gave up multiple times. The "Clear" button actually worked! I can't believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure whether we are talking about the same thing here, but my open/save file dialog just hang for 20 minutes not responding.

These are the things i did that eventually fixed the problem:

1. Check system drive errors
2. [run sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)
3. Search -> "indexing options"-> advanced -> rebuild
4. Check for malwares

[image: indexing options]

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends this is my first post.

**After working for four days I find this solution by myself**

Try checking in safe mode first if its working fine, just uninstall One Drive in safe mode using I obit uninstaller and remember to do power scan once done restart in normal mode and it should work and also change performance in performance tab

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(an answer has been accepted) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. 
When you had your problem did the dialog windows open slow in other than one drive windows?
Can you reinstall one drive?
Could you explain the performance tab?
Please read.Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, Again welcome to superuser and keep coming back, Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem trying to save ilustrator files, and freezing my silhouette studio software on startup splash. Illustrator froze after clicking the Save button, after days of trying many things I found it was the printers. I had a network printer added that wasn't available anymore.

I deleted all printers in control panel and the problem dissapeared.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same issue now in 2019, and none of the solutions I found worked for me. What did finally work was something quite simple: restart Windows in Safe Mode, and then restart again in normal mode. Problem gone!
Don't know if this will work for you, but it's fairly easy to try. Good luck!

Comment: This may resolve symptoms temporarily but it does not address the problem and so is not a solution.